# Decodificar valor datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime

De una base de datos me viene una fecha y hora con la siguiente forma `2019-11-06T19:55:59.865Z`. Yo ahora mismo tengo un conjunto de líneas que mediante `split()` al final obtengo la fecha y hora sin problemas.

```
timestamp = str(df.loc[r]['timestamp'])
x = timestamp.split('T')
date = x[0].split('-')
y, mo, d = date[0], date[1], date[2]
time = x[1].split('.')
time = time[0].split(':')
h, mi, s = time[0], time[1], time[2]
```

Pero supuse que ya debe haber algo mucho más directo y encontré la librería `datetime`. Pero intento emplearla y me da problemas.

```
from datetime import date

tt = df.loc[r]['timestamp']
d = datetime.strptime(tt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
print(d)
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> time data '2019-11-01T13:58:12.966Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'

Lo cual pienso que es o por mis milisegundos `%f` o la `T`.
Para escribir los diferentes parámetros me he basado en la tabla que aparece [en esta página web](https://www.journaldev.com/23365/python-string-to-datetime-strptime).

¿Alguna ayuda?

Gracias

Comment: Quita el `%` delante de la Z

Comment: ¿lo puedes poner cómo respuesta? O si es muy trivial la borro xD Gracias!!

Comment: Hecho. Pero para que pueda ser más útil, he explicado el por qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la cadena de formato `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z'` has usado al final `%Z` la cual significa, según la web enlazada en la pregunta, o según la [propia documentación de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

- Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive). Ejemplos: (empty), UTC, EST, CST

Es decir, se trata del nombre de una zona horaria. Resulta que tu cadena tiene simplemente una Z en esa posición:

```
2019-11-06T19:55:59.865Z
```

y Z no es el nombre de ninguna zona horaria, sino un carácter especial de la [especificación ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), que significa que la hora está en UTC (*Coordinated Universal Time*) y por tanto no tiene zona horaria (tendría un offset 0 con respecto al meridiano de Greenwich).

En definitiva, que puesto que lo que tienes es una "Z" literal, y no una zona horaria, en tu cadena de formato debes usar también una Z literal (igual que la T literal que pusiste entre la fecha y la hora). Es decir:

```
'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

**Bonus**. En realidad el estándar ISO-8601 se parece mucho al RFC 3339 y ambos tienen bastantes variaciones sobre el formato que te has encontrado. Lo más genérico para tratar con todos ellos sería instalar [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) y dejarle que "adivine" el formato en que está la cadena y que lo convierta adecuadamente, con algo tan simple como:

```
import dateutil.parser

tt = "2019-11-06T19:55:59.865Z"
d = dateutil.parser.parse(tt)

# sale datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 6, 19, 55, 59, 865000, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es conseguir año, mes y día se puede hacer así:

```
from datetime import datetime
tt = df.loc[r]['timestamp']
d = datetime.strptime(tt.split('T')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
print(d, d.year, d.month, d.day)
```